# Import and use class in vuejs component inside template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a vuejs / laravel form to update user settings. After some struggle i am not at the validation handling. I'm using laravels return validation to add error messages below input fields for errors. The way it is return requires me to somehow handle how i "get" the error.

My problem is that i can't seem to find out how to import a class inside my component and use it from the template. As you can see in EditUser.vue i am trying to get the error via the imported class as `v-text="errors.get('name')"`

So could anyone help me with how to either change my approach to this or get what i'm working on to work properly.

edit.blade.php:

```
<edit-user-form user-array="{{ $user }}" 
route="{{ route('user.update', $user) }}"></edit-user-form>
```

EditUser.vue:

```
<template>
  <form method="POST" action="update" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
     <input id="name" type="text" name="name" v-model="user.name">
       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
         <strong v-text="errors.get('name')"></strong>
     </span>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import {Errors} from '../errors.js';
export default {
    props: ['userArray', 'route'],
    data() {
        return {
            user: JSON.parse(this.userArray)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            axios.post(this.route, this.user)
                .then(response => alert('Success'))
                .catch(error => Errors.record(error.response.data));
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

error.js:

```
export class Errors {
    constructor() {
        this.errors = {};
    }

    get(field) {
        if (this.erros[field]) {
            return this.errors[field][0];
        }
    }
    record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `v-text="errors.get('name')"` is looking for a vue data type called `errors`. Your import is a blank import. It's not being referenced by anything

Comment: @Varcorb Yeah i figured that, would you say i somehow need to call it inside the data return and how would i do that?

Comment: try after your `return {user: JSON.parse(this.userArray),errors: Errors}`

Comment: @Varcorb i tried that before, it gives me this error "Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.errors.get is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the variables used in `template` tag of single file component are, basically, prefixed with `this`, when interpreted by Vue. Therefore, in order to make certain variables accessible, we have to attach them to current component's instance.

Easy solution to most cases, specially, if it is locally/rarely used variable is to assign `Errors` class to component's `data` option:

```
data () {
   return {
      user: JSON.parse(this.userArray),
      errors: new Errors()
   }
},
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        axios.post(this.route, this.user)
            .then(response => alert('Success'))
            .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data));
    }
}
```

I've put `new` keyword there, as this implementation makes sense if each component will use it's own instance of `Errors` class.

If the goal is to share `Errors` class and access error bag within application, it can be added to `Vue.prototype` and access via `this` from any component. [Here](https://dev.to/nkoik/writing-a-very-simple-plugin-in-vuejs---example-8g8) is one of many articles to help create custom plugin.

Depending on the goal current implemetation is trying to achieve, there may be better options, like [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) or re-usable error/alert components, that can handle error responses.

Comment: thank you, this worked. Thanks for providing additional documentation and ideas on how i can approach this differently.